# Connect to DMN and BPMN through REST API Camunda

Tags: rest, camunda, camunda-modeler

I'm trying to connect to my DMN model and BPMN Model through Postman ,My DMN diagram in camunda looks as below
[image]

I have Deployed it as below
[image]

And im  trying to access it through Postman as below
[image]

The video i have referenced is [Video Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8dWMFSMJNE&ab_channel=Camunda) the only change i have is i'm working with latest camunda 8 and the latest camunda modeler 5.0.0

Any help, guidance or reference will be a great help

Answer (score 2):

The REST API you are using only exists in Camunda 7 (https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/reference/rest/). In Camunda 8 the underlying architecture is completely redesigned and applies CQRS. The APIs are documented here: https://docs.camunda.io/docs/apis-clients/public-api/

You may also find this helpful: https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/camunda-8-api-postman-collection

Directly evaluating a decision is posisble as shown here: https://docs.camunda.io/docs/apis-tools/java-client-examples/decision-evaluate/.

You no longer need to use the DMN in a BPMN and start a process instance to evaluate the DMN via API as it was the case in early Camunda 8 versions.

Comment: Is this still the case in 2024?

Comment: no: https://docs.camunda.io/docs/apis-tools/java-client-examples/decision-evaluate/